# Catching a drag exit in Qt?

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I've got a custom widget descended from QWidget that I want to be able to drop onto, and while the drag is hovering over the widget I'd like to highlight it to provide a little visual feedback to the user.   Seems to me the simplest way to do this would be to highlight when dragEnterEvent is called and unhighlight when the drag exits the widget, but how can I catch the drag exit?  There doesn't seem to be a dragExitEvent event handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Assistant on the Index tab, type "drag*event" and you will find [`dragLeaveEvent`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#dragLeaveEvent). :)