# Python: Drag from pyqt5 to folder/desktop

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I have this script that allows dragging a file to a pyqt5 gui and receiving its path:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from idna import unicode


class MainWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Drag to here")
        self.resize(720, 480)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        files = [unicode(u.toLocalFile()) for u in event.mimeData().urls()]
        for f in files:
            print(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = MainWidget()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The only problem is that I would like to drag a file **from** the pyqt5 gui **to** the desktop/folder. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching a drag exit in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848430/catching-a-drag-exit-in-qt)

Comment: @Kraay89 THank you but no because I would like to drag a file from the gui to the desktop